# Determinar cuál de los dos elementos de texto es mayor en un array

Tags: javascript, array

A partir del siguiente array que se proporciona:

```
var valores = [true, 5, false, "hola", "adios", 2];
```

- Determinar cuál de los dos elementos de texto es mayor

Estoy aprendiendo JS pero aun no tengo mucha experiencia, como resolverían este problema de la manera más optima ? muchas gracias a todos.

por ejemplo para el primer punto lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
var valores = [true, 5, false, "hola", "adios", 2];

var strings = valores.filter((elemento) => {
        return typeof(elemento) === 'string';
    });

var mayor;

strings.forEach( (elemento) => {
    if( mayor ){
        if ( elemento.length > mayor.length ){
            mayor = elemento;
        }
    }
    else {
        mayor = elemento;
    }
} );

console.log(mayor); // retorna adios
```

note: lo realicé con lo poco que sé de JS, estoy seguro de que debe haber una forma más fácil, y con menos lineas de código.

Comment: No he podido entender a que se refieren en esa pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una optimización común a todos los lenguajes: no duplicar cosas. Es decir, intenta calcular **sin realizar copias** de ningún elemento.

Además, intenta minimizar el número de pasadas sobre un *array*. En tu código, *recorres* el *array* completo una vez, creando un nuevo *array* con copias de los elementos ... y luego recorres ese *array* recién creado realizando cálculos. ¿ No sería mucho mejor hacerlo **en una sola pasada** ?

```js
const valores = [ true, 5, false, "hola", "adios", 2 ];
var max = 0;
var maxString;

valores.forEach( function( val ) {
  if( ( typeof( val ) == 'string' ) && ( val.length > max ) ) {
    max = val.length;
    maxString = val;
  }
} );

console.log( maxString );
```

Comment: el problema es que me está capturando el tamaño, no el elemento string con el tamaño más grande.

Comment: @StivenTrujillo Ya. Ahora uso 2 variables ... se podría hacer con 1 sola igualmente, a costa de visitar varias veces un mismo índice del *array* ... sin llegar a tener que recorrerlo entero, empeora el rendimiento. Con 2 variables no hay ese problema.

Comment: Tienes razón, la utilización de dos variables es lo más optimo. partiendo de tu código intente acomodarlo con una sola variable,  y se me anidaron muchos if xD.

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando el método [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) de `Array` podrías evitarte el paso intermedio de filtrado.

En el primer paso, compruebas que el tipo que recibes sea de tipo `String`, si no lo es, devuelves el valor anterior.

En el segundo paso compruebas si la cadena anterior es mayor que la actual, y en base a eso devuelves una u otra.

```js
const valores = [true, 5, false, "hola", "adios", 2];

const mayor = valores.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if(typeof curr !== 'string') return prev;
  return prev.length > curr.length ? prev : curr;
}, '');

console.log(mayor);
```

Se podría reducir aún más agrupando las condiciones y utilizando las propiedades de las `funciones flecha`:

```js
const valores = [true, 5, false, "hola", "adios", 2];

const mayor = valores.reduce((prev, curr) => typeof curr === 'string' && (curr.length > prev.length) ? curr : prev, '');

console.log(mayor);
```

Comment: Excelente solución

Answer (score 2):

En el punto 1

- Iteramos sobre los valores con el ciclo `filter` para obtener solo aquellos cuyo `typeof` sea de tipo `string`, eso nos generará un vector nuevo solo con las 2 palabras del vector original, el cual comparamos en un operador ternario de acuerdo con sus posiciones y usando la propiedad length

```js
    var valores = [true, 5, false, "hola", "adios", 2];
    
    let palabras = valores.filter((element) => typeof element === "string")

    let mayor = (palabras[0].length > palabras[1].length) ? palabras[0] : palabras[1]
     console.log(mayor)
```

Para el punto 2

- Simplemente podemos sumar por medio de sus posiciones en el vector tanto el valor de `true` como el valor de `false` lo cual retornará `true`

```js
    let sumaVerdad = valores[0] + valores[2]
    console.log(sumaVerdad)
```

Dentro del mismo punto 2

- Podemos multiplicar los valores booleanos lo cual me dará `false`

```js
    let sumaFalsedad = (valores[0] * valores[2])
    console.log(sumaFalsedad)
```

Comment: Pero solo funcionaría para ese Array no?, o otro array con solo dos strings, no funcionaría para cualquier tipo de Array con tamaño n, en el que se quiera obtener el string mayor. corrígeme si estoy equivocado.

Comment: Bueno @StivenTrujillo, es por qué mi respuesta se basa en tu duda, para que el código sea dinámico a cualquier longitud de vector entonces la solución variaría

Comment: @BetaM, sin embargo, estuve probando el primer _Snippet_ de tu publicación y funciona en diferentes longitudes del `Array` con cadenas de diferentes longitudes. Probé las soluciones de cada uno y funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo resolví de esta manera.

```js
let valores = [ true, 5, false, "hola", "adios", 2];

// capturamos solo los strings
valores = valores.filter(item => typeof item == 'string')

// ordenar los strings de mayor a menor
// si quieres de menor a mayor usa a.length - b.length
valores = valores.sort( (a, b) => b.length - a.length )

console.log( valores[0] ) // retorna adios..
```

Comment: no entendí la parte de la función sort, que es a y b y por que se restan?

Comment: yo lo haria asi mismo me parece la forma mas entendible aunque la mas eficiente es con reduce

Answer (score 2):

> Mediante reduce se verifica que el valor del acumulador sea siempre
> el del string de mayor longitud

```js
var valores = [1, true, "hola", "adios", false];

var palabras = valores.filter((p) => typeof p == 'string');

var masLarga = palabras.reduce((acc, element) => {
  acc = element.length > acc.length ? element : acc
  return acc;
}, "");

console.log(masLarga);
```

Answer (score 1):

yo lo hice de la siguiente manera

```
 let valores = [true,5,false,"hola","adios",2];

//1.Determinar cual de los dos elementos de texto es mayor
var inter=0;
var mayor;
valores.forEach((valor)=>{
  
 typeof valor == "string" ? valor.length>inter ? (mayor=valor,inter=valor.length ):false:false;

})
console.log(mayor);
```

por supuesto que se puede hacer en menos lineas, pero para mi es mas dificil de leer

```
let valores = [true,5,false,"hola","adios",2];

//1.Determinar cual de los dos elementos de texto es mayor
var inter=0;
var mayor;
valores.forEach(valor => typeof valor == "string" ? valor.length>inter ? (mayor=valor,inter=valor.length ):false:false)
console.log(mayor);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
esto lo hice de una forma básica y con la información que ya no da 
el array.

    let valores = [true,5,false,"hola","adios",2];

    let string1 = valores[3].length
    let string2 = valores[4].length

    if(){
    console.log(valores[3])
    }else{
    console.log(valores[4])
    }
```

Comment: Formatea como texto lo que es texto